# "Programar un proceso en lenguaje C y que se ejecuten a cierta hora" en Linux

Tags: c, linux, bash, cron, ubuntu-server

Programar un proceso en lenguaje `C` y que se ejecuten a cierta hora.
He estado revisando comandos como `crontab` y `at` pero en la mayoría de casos solo veo que se pueden programar scripts `.sh`, y lo que me da la compilación en `gcc` es `.out`.

También he visto poner al inicio el código en `c` que se cambie el intérprete de `/bin/sh` al de `C` pero no se si eso sea posible o por último crear un script que pueda ejecutar la salida del gcc.

El proyecto marca que debo usar `C` para crear el código pero en pocas palabras no sé como temporizarlo. El proyecto es en Ubuntuserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberas crear un programa con tu rutina escrita en `c` por ejemplo `mi_rutina.c` que incluya el siguiente código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf ("Esta es mi rutina");
    return 0;
}
```

Compilas el programa como sigue como sigue:

```sh
gcc mi_rutina.c -o mi_rutina
```

Ahora ya tenemos un programa ejecutable en Linux solo basta con darle permisos de ejecución para ello lo hacemos como sigue:

```sh
chmod +x mi_rutina
```

Una vez hecho esto para ejecutar el programa emitimos el siguiente comando:

```sh
.\mi_rutina
```

Si lo quieres ejecutar desde cualquier lugar sin poner la ruta puedes agregarlo a la variable `PATH` o moverlo para la ruta `/usr/local/bin/` debes tener permisos de `sudo` y lo haces como sigue:

```sh
mv mi_rutina /usr/local/bin/
```

Para agregarlo como rutina a cierta hora del día utilizaremos `cron` para ello emitiremos el comando siguiente:

```sh
crontab -e
```

Se abrira el archivo de cron y ahí agregaras tu tarea a ejecutarse como sigue:

```sh
5 4 * * * mi_rutina && echo "rutina exitosa"
```

El comando `echo "rutina exitosa"` solo se va a ejecutar si el programa en `mi_rutina` se ejecuta correctamente, además se ejecutará cadá día a las **4:05AM**.

Puedes generar intervalos de ejecución en la siguiente [aquí](https://crontab.guru/) y puedes obtener más información de cron [aquí](https://www.redeszone.net/2017/01/09/utilizar-cron-crontab-linux-programar-tareas/).

Debes tener en cuenta que tu programa solo podrá acceder a información a la cual tiene acceso el usuario que esta programando la tarea, si quieres que tenga acceso total debes emitir crontab -e como usuario `root`.

Answer (score 1):

No hay restricciones, puedes utilizar cualquier ejecutable en cron. De cualquier modo, incluso si solo aceptara scripts, dentro del mismo script puedes llamar a tu proceso (sea C o de cualquier otro tipo).
La ventaja de utilizar scripts es que puedes agregar configuración de ambiente si es requerida por tu proceso.